# sound design / sound art / post-production magazine recommendation

Tags: magazine

hello,

i've previously posted a question regarding magazine recommendations... however i'm posting this again to try and attack the issue from a different angle: i find it difficult a hard-copy magazine which covers my interests. i'm looking for something with less gear reviews, less about how to record the next big hit. more sound design / post-production theory, technique, sound-art... perhaps a mag aimed more towards the creative sound designer/engineer rather than the 'electronic musician'.

can anyone advise? i'm looking into Resolution Magazine and Music Tech Magazine... anyone subscribed to those?

thanks,
K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've probably mentioned it ad nauseum in various posts on this site, but I've really been enjoying The New Soundtrack (formerly The Soundtrack). It's an academic journal published twice a year. It deals much more with the aesthetics, and critical sutdies (i.e. Marxist, Feminist, Semiotic, etc.), of film sound. There's always an article or two about some classic work of sound film, but there's a consistent effort to approach more modern pieces and ideas. Regardless, there's always a ton of information about how sound contributes to the story in a film, and how it affects **perception** of the story.

Like I mentioned, it's an academic journal. So, it's a bit on the pricey side, but well worth it if you can afford it. Here's a link to [the latest issue](http://www.euppublishing.com/journal/sound) (Oct. 2011).

Don't forget to check out the [Motion Picture Editor's Guild Magazine](https://www.editorsguild.com/Magazine.cfm) and [CAS Quarterly](http://cinemaaudiosociety.org/quarterly/index.php) newsletters either. Both are available to read online for free.

Comment: +1 Editors Guild Mag has some great stuff, that is, when the issues features sound rather than picture ;)  Great article by Charles Maynes about 2 issues ago regarding some cheap but good plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Resolution is rather good, especially for post. It does require a paid subscription though (not that that's a bad thing).

I read [Audio Media](http://www.audiomedia.com) as they have a free online only subscription. Again it's quite good for post sound, but not as much as Resolution.

Comment: I'll second Audio Media. You can also get a free print copy if you live in Europe, otherwise it's £75. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Looked at The Mix magazine? Often articles with sound designers discussing theory and techniques etc in there.

Answer (score 1):

[Sound on Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/). Covers all things.. soundy... Recording techniques, interviews with all sorts of audio professionals from stereotypical post guys to some audio analysists in the police force. Of course it has the usual reviews on plug-ins, equipment etc, but also lots of other things. A decent all-round magazine.

Not sure if it's just available in the UK though!

Comment: haha, SOS is a UK based mag. :)

Comment: I know, I meant I didn't know if it was only available in the UK, or if you can get it elsewhere! =P


Comment: You can get SOS everywhere in Europe, even on subscription. They happily sent it every month when I lived in The Netherlands, and continued to do so when I moved to Germany.