# Interesting Sound Journals? 

Tags: sound-theory

Hi all.

Just had a look at a recent DesigningSound post which took me to Cinephile (Uni of British Colombia Film Journal). Had a look at their archives and theres an intereseting volume called Sound on Screen from 2010 (http://www.cinephile.ca/files/vol6no1-complete-withbleed.pdf).

Anyone else know of any hidden jem journals related to film (or game) sound they'd care to share too? :)

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 3):

I keep mentioning The Soundtrack/The New Soundtrack over and over, and all over the place to boot. You should really pay more attention. ;)

It was originally [The Soundtrack, published by Intellect](http://www.intellectbooks.co.uk/journals/view-journal,id=146/), and you may still be able to get back issues through that link. It is now called [The New Soundtrack, published by Edinburgh University Press](http://www.euppublishing.com/journal/sound). It's a journal put together by [The School of Sound](http://schoolofsound.co.uk), and it's editorial board includes, among many others, Michel Chion, Randy Thom and Walter Murch. While I'm mentioning the School of Sound, you may also want to look into the book [Soundscape: The School of Sound Lectures 1998-2001](http://schoolofsound.co.uk/content/book.htm)...another publication of theirs.

You may also want to check out [this thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/sound-design-sound-art-post-production-magazine-recommendation), which has a host of other excellent suggestions.

Comment: Ooops! My bad, sorry Shaun :p 
I did think of the Soundtrack but forgot to mention it in my post! One of my former tutors helps put it together. A bit on the pricey side for me unfortunately :/ Was nice to get the 1st edition free while still at Uni though! I'll revisit that previous post again now. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. There's also [Music, Sound and the Moving Image](http://www.liverpooluniversitypress.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=53%3a..), it's not available for free though.