# Academic Papers

Tags: academic

I'm looking for academic papers on the subject of film sound and sound design. Does anyone know of any good online resources for such things?

I'm a masters student and I'm basically just looking for inspiration at this point so the topic can be almost anything. Any suggestions of particular papers or essays would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For academic works, try [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com), an excellent search engine that has indexed a cornucopia of academic publications. In addition, if you're enrolled at a college or university, don't hesitate to take advantage of the research librarian(s).

Answer (score 0):

[Interesting Sound Journals?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12878/interesting-sound-journals) 
http://www.soundstudies.eu/journals/

Answer (score 0):

Good source is AES (Audio Engineering Society - http://www.aes.org) - If you are Student you have very interesting pricing options.